# UIViewController: how to show data from sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiviewcontroller

This is how I get my data from the db to show on a UITableViewController

```
        Jobs *jobs = [self.job objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = jobs.jName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = jobs.jTags;
```

When a table view cell  is clicked in the Table ViewController :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"showJobDetail"]) { NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Jobs *jobs = [self.job objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; [[segue destinationViewController]setJID:jobs.jID];}
}
```

This is my theory on how I would pass it to UIViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    Jobs *jobs = [self.job];

    if (jobs != nil) {
        [self.jNameLabel setText:jobs.jName];
        [self.jDescLabel setText:jobs.jDesc];
        [self.jEarningsLabel setText:jobs.jEarnings];
    }
}
```

ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.job = [CourseFindrDB db].job;
}
```

What seems to be wrong? I know there's a missing syntax or something.

Comment: Do you have the data in UIViewController? If you have it try run the code in viewDidLoad method instead viewWillAppeare. Do you try to open UIViewController (and pass the data) when you click on the table view cell?

Comment: @Greg I have my data in sqlite. My viewDidLoad is:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.job = [CourseFindrDB db].job;
}

also YES. When I click a table view cell it goes to a UIViewController to show details

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your viewDidLoad method to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *jobs = [CourseFindrDB db].job;

    if (jobs != nil && jobs.count > 0) {
        //You can log your jobs for debugging
        NSLog(@"%@", jobs.jName);
        Jobs *j = jobs[0];
        [self.jNameLabel setText:j.jName];
        [self.jDescLabel setText:j.jDesc];
        [self.jEarningsLabel setText:j.jEarnings];
    }
    else
       NSLog(@"jobs is nil or has no data"); // Added for debugging purpose
}
```

And remove viewWillAppear: In viewWillAppeare your outlets aren't ready yet so this is why you don't have a result.

Comment: It says 'Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Jobs *' with an expression of 'NSArray *'

Comment: @hazelvan see edited post. It looks like  your [CourseFindrDB db].job returns NSArray not single Jobs object. If it doesn't work try what kind of object contain jobs array.

Comment: It crashes. Weird thing, I don't have my 'Jobs' set as NSArray. I set a property of NSArray 'job' in the header file of the ViewController

Comment: Do you know where it's crashes, which line?

Comment: BTW, the crash note was this: 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CourseFindrViewController setJID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89a4b60'`

Comment: JID is the ID of the data attributes

Comment: Can you put log after line NSArray*jobs... -> NSLog(@"jobs: %@", NSStringFromClass([jobs class])); and another as a first line in if statement NSLog(@"first object: %@", NSStringFromClass([jobs[0] class])); and let me know what the console says.

Comment: Still crashed. Here's the crashes:
`2014-01-10 00:50:27.030 CourseFindr[5913:a0b] -[CourseFindrViewController setJID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89471c0
2014-01-10 00:50:27.043 CourseFindr[5913:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CourseFindrViewController setJID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89471c0'`

Comment: Can you just after [super viewDidLoad]; add another log: NSLog(@"FIRST CALL: %@", NSStringFromClass([[CourseFindrDB db].job class])); It looks like this issue is in different place in your code where you call setJID in CourseFindrViewController. I recommended you to review this class.

Comment: The issue appears in your prepareForSegue: method -> [[segue destinationViewController]setJID:jobs.jID];. I don't know the view hierarchy but you should cast the destination view to your CourseFindrViewController. If you use navigation controller or tab bar controller your destination view will refer to that and you need to get it from appropriate controller.

Comment: The hierarchy is supposed to be Navigation -> TableVC -> VC ; I thought I should put the ID, so that it corresponds to the pushed cell in the TableVC. Should I remove the ID then?

Comment: Do you use storyboard? Is your CourseFindrViewController a separate view controller in storyboard or is embeded in nag controller? The best way to see what is that is call NSLog(@"VIEW: %@", NSStringFromClass([[segue destinationViewController] class])); in prepareForSegue inside if identifier is equal to string statement.